# table view not showing

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, cocoa-touch

I'm working on this app, but somehow, its not returning any rows in my tableviewcontroller.
here is my code:

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
#define kStudentenURL [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/api/api.php"] 

#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"


@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSArray *_studenten; } @end

@implementation MasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib]; }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // The hud will dispable all input on the view (use the higest view possible in the view hierarchy)     HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];  [self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];        // Regiser for HUD callbacks so we can remove it from the window at the right time  HUD.delegate = self;        // Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread  [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(getJsonDataFromServer) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES]; }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. }


-(void)getJsonDataFromServer {
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        kStudentenURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    }); }

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:responseData                           
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];

    _studenten = [json objectForKey:@"studenten"];

    NSLog(@"Studenten: %@", _studenten);
    NSLog(@"%u", _studenten.count); }

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1; }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _studenten.count; }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *student = [_studenten objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *studentNaam = [student objectForKey:@"studentNaam"];
    NSString *studentAchterNaam = [student objectForKey:@"studentAchterNaam"];

    cell.textLabel.text = studentAchterNaam;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = studentNaam;


    return cell; }

/* // Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath { }
*/

/* // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES; }
*/

/*- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    } }*/

@end
```

I know my json is comming in correctly. the `NSLog`s are returning the data i ask, but i cant seem to get any rows. Can someone give me a hand? tnx

Comment: Does it ever hit the cellForRowAtIndex method?

Comment: i've added a short NSLog right underneath the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath call, and its not getting loged, any ID why?

Comment: I completely missed the fact that you weren't ever calling reloadData on your tableview. After you've updated the data, you need to manually tell it that it needs to reload.

Comment: are you sure _studenten.count is not returning 0 when numberOfRowsInSection is called?

Comment: @Kyle _studenten.count returns 2 acording to the nslog

Comment: @shortstuffsushi how and where can i do this, i've never realy worked with dynamic tabels

Comment: Updated in my answer. You'll need to add a reference to your tableview. Make sure to hook it up in storyboard!

Comment: if you put a break point in cellForRowAtIndexPath it never gets hit? but numberOfRowsInSection returns 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer -- you need to call [(your tableview) reloadData] once you've finished loading that data array!

Presumably you've got your tableview on the storyboard right now, and you've set it's datasource and delegate to your view controller. You will also need to have a property in your view controller to that tableview. You might have some code that looks like this.

```
@interface MasterViewController () {
    NSArray *_studenten;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation MasterViewController
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData                           
                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

    _studenten = [json objectForKey:@"studenten"];

    NSLog(@"Studenten: %@", _studenten);
    NSLog(@"%u", _studenten.count);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are never getting a valid cell returned from `dequeueReusableCell`. What I recommend doing is after you try to reuse a cell, check to see if it is nil, if so you need to alloc a new cell. I've added the code to your function.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    NSDictionary *student = [_studenten objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *studentNaam = [student objectForKey:@"studentNaam"];
    NSString *studentAchterNaam = [student objectForKey:@"studentAchterNaam"];

    cell.textLabel.text = studentAchterNaam;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = studentNaam;

    return cell; }
```